# LINQ: transform enumerable until end condition is met, and return if the end condition was met

Tags: c#, linq, out

I have a string enumerable `strArr`. I want to convert all entries into `int` as long as that is possible, and when an entry is not convertible to `int`, enumeration should stop. I also want to return a `bool` that tells me if converting all entries was possible or not.

So what I am looking for is kind of the enumerable version of `int.TryParse` (it returns both a bool if converting was successful and the converted value).

I thought it could be done with LINQ, but I can't figure it out. Here are my thoughts:

```
strArr.
    Select(s => { bool b = int.TryParse(s, out int i); return (i, b); }).
        // returns both the converted int value and the parsing bool for each entry
    TakeWhile(ib => ib.b).
        // will stop when the first parsing bool was false
    Select(ib => i).ToArray();
        // will only take the ints from the (int, bool) pairs and return an array
```

This solution will give me the converted entries as an array, but it will not tell me if conversion was successful. I need a way to `out` either the bool or the enumerable, but how?

I know I could compare lengths of `strArr` and the returned int array to see if conversion was successful. But I want to learn about LINQ usage, not just solve the problem at hand (I could always just do some looping and never use LINQ at all).

Comment: Have a `wasSuccess` bool variable before the LINQ set to `true`. In the select do `wasSuccess = wasSuccess && b;` (actually even just `wasSuccess = b;` would work due to your `TakeWhile`). Check the value of `wasSuccess` to see whether all values converted successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is meant to do: `Select(ib => i)`.  There is no `i` in that context.  Are you just trying to select only the integer from your `ib` object?  If you're only selecting the integer then that would explain why you're not also getting the `bool` property on the resulting array elements.  `ib` contains both the parsed `int` and the `bool`.  Isn't that what you're looking for?  Though it seems strange because the resulting `bool` would *always* be `true` for every array element.

Comment: *"but it will not tell me if conversion was successful"* - If there *are* converted results then conversion was successful for those elements.  It's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for here.  What is your starting data and what would a successful result of data be?

Comment: You already return tuple in first select, why not do the same in last one?

Comment: @mjwills: And the OP already has that information and already knows how to observe it.  If the resulting collection is smaller than the original collection, not all elements were converted.  This looks like an attempt to drastically overcomplicate a simple `if` statement.  Even with setting a `bool` in the conversion, one still needs to write an `if` statement *after* the conversion to check the `bool`.  So what's being saved by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mjwills' little hint I got it:

```
bool parseSuccess = true;
int[] intArr = strArr.
    Select(s => { parseSuccess &= int.TryParse(s, out int i); return i; }).
    TakeWhile(i => parseSuccess).ToArray();
```

Comment: That will return `true` if `strArr` is empty - is that what you want? _It may be, I am just clarifying._

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In an empty string array, nothing fails conversion, so there is no reason to return `false`.

Comment: Though this will work, I personally don't like to make side effects on local variables inside linq statements.

Comment: LINQ is functional programming and it kind of violates it because there are side effects.

Comment: I don't really see the benefit here.  After this conversion you still need to examine the results.  You were trying to avoid having to write an `if` statement to compare the collection lengths, and did so by introducing an `if` statement to check the `parseSuccess` value.  So to avoid writing an `if` statement, you introduced an `if` statement (and complicated the LINQ expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Mutating a variable from inside lambda should be avoided, because it leads to a rather fragile code.

You could make your own `TakeWhilePlusOne` method that gives you the first entry that failed the predicate, like this:

```
static class EnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhilePlusOne<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    ,   Func<TSource,bool> predicate
    ) {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        return TakeWhilePlusOneIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhilePlusOneIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            var stop = !predicate(element);
            yield return element;
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this implementation is a modification of [`TakeWhile` in the reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

Now you can use this method to achieve your goal as follows:

```
var pairs = strArr
    .Select(s => new { ParseSuccess = int.TryParse(s, out int i), Value = i })
    .TakeWhilePlusOne(i => i.ParseSuccess)
    .ToArray();
var intArray = pairs.Where(p => p.ParseSuccess).Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
var allValuesAreGood = pairs.LastOrDefault()?.ParseSuccess ?? true;
```

You could also use [`TakeUntil` from morelinq library](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) (thanks [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) for the comment):

```
var pairs = strArr
    .Select(s => new { ParseSuccess = int.TryParse(s, out int i), Value = i })
    .TakeUntil(i => !i.ParseSuccess)
    .ToArray();
var intArray = pairs.Where(p => p.ParseSuccess).Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
var allValuesAreGood = pairs.LastOrDefault()?.ParseSuccess ?? true;
```

Comment: What happens if `strArr` is empty? Also it may be worth checking https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs since it does something similar.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the comment. I fixed the empty array issue, and mentioned `TakeUntil`.